# trying to get firebase realtime database working in react, what is wrong with this code segment?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

As the title said, I'm trying to get firebase realtime database working on a small react app. I can't figure out what's wrong with this segment of code; I know (using alert) that it's being executed, and all the variables such as uid hold the correct value (again using alert), but the realtime database (read, write permission already opened) isn't being updated at all. any help is appreciated.

```
export const addAddress = (
  suiteNumber,
  streetNumber,
  streetName,
  cityName,
  province
) => {
  var user = auth.currentUser;
  var firebaseRef = fire
    .database()
    .ref()
    .child("users");
  firebaseRef.child(user.uid).set({
    suiteNumber: suiteNumber,
    streetNumber: streetNumber,
    streetName: streetName,
    cityName: cityName,
    province: province
  });
};
```

Comment: Change `var firebaseRef = fire.database().ref().child("users");` to `var firebaseRef = fire.database().ref("users");`

Comment: To make things much simpler, you can even do
`fire.database().ref("users/" + user.uid).set({fieldshere})`

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. Can you reproduce this with hardcoded values? If so, can you see if you can reproduce on a site like jsbin?